# Can someone help me identify this bonsai sprout?

Tags: trees, bonsai, pines, sprouting

[image]
I planted it from a Bonsai kit. The seed packet is labeled as Black Pine seeds but, in comparison to photos online, these sprouts seem suspicious.[image]
Another sprout came up, it looks more like a pine seed![image]
The initial sprout got tall.

Comment: It is certainly not pine, these starter kits are often scams. I had one too, it is okay for the pot but for the bonsai you can better find something in the wild (seedling or small plant).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I guess I'm just going to have to wait for them to grow in order to find out what they are (haha).

Comment: Yes, it is a surprise :D I can't tell which species it is, maybe when your plants are a bit larger. I do know that it is probably a deciduous tree species. For more guidance about starting bonsai this [site](https://www.bonsaiempire.com/basics/cultivation) might be helpful.

Comment: I'll be sure to post an updated inquiry when it's more fully grown. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your sprouts with the paddle shaped leaves (in the topmost photo) certainly aren't pine sprouts, ... but in the photo second down from the top, where we see the sprout over to the right which looks like a lanky arm with little green fingers sticking into the brown shell of a seed...That looks to me like it very well *might* be a pine sprout, as you say. Keep your eye on it.

Answer (score 1):

These look like [*Centaurea cyanus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centaurea_cyanus) seedlings. I have grown them a few times and your seedlings remind me of them. Of course, many seedlings look similar when in this stage, so I'm not 100% sure. Below there's a picture of my seedlings:

[image]

Comment: They look indeed very much alike. It is impossible to make bonsai out of these (annual) plants :(

Comment: @b.nota Hopefully the package contained real black pine seeds that will sprout soon, probably in the middle of the pot.